# How to use Facebook PHP SDK with Yii 2?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, yii2

I am trying to implement `Facebook` `SDK` for `PHP` with `Yii 2`. I am totally new to this and doing this in my `config` file:

```
'facebook' => [
            'class' => 'frontend/components/Facebook/Facebook'
        ]
```

The 'Facebook' folder is placed inside components folder, inside frontend. I am trying to include it like this:

```
use Facebook/Facebook;
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do it right? Any help regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Facebook` class you should have namespace:

```
namespace frontend\components\facebook;
```

And then use this like:

```
use frontend\components\Facebook\Facebook;
```

If u defined it in components in `config` just use it like:

```
\Yii::$app->facebook
```

Answer (score 1):

it you are doing social login yii2-eauth is best for every type of social login....

check git code [here](https://github.com/Nodge/yii2-eauth)

Checkout demo [here](http://nodge.ru/yii-eauth/demo2/login)